# My divs won't line up -

Tags: css, html

If i style for chrome it works but not in Firefox and vise versa - at the moment I have styles set for Firefox http://www.mhinteriors.com.au/new/. I want the layout to look the way it does now in Firefox. But I need it to work in Chrome and IE. IE doesn't seem to like background image 100%?

```
 .header {
 background-image:url(../images/banner-2.jpg);
 background-size:100% auto;
 box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
 left:0;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:800;
 padding:8px;
 }

#wrapper {
max-width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}

/*BRAND DETAILS*/
.logo {
float:left;
margin-left:30px;
padding-top:10px;
width:8%;
}

.brand-title {
float:left;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:5px;
width:50%;
}

.brand-subtitle {
float:left;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:25px;
width:60%;
}


/*SOCIAL BUTTONS*/
.socials {
float:right;
height:80px;
position:relative;
right:0;
top:100px;
width:35%;
z-index:900;
}

.facebook {
float:left;
width:60px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.pinterest,.blogger,.instagram {
float:left;
width:60px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 50px;
}


/*NAVIGATION*/
.nav-container {
float:right;
position:fixed;
right:40px;
top:145px;
width:60%;
z-index:800;
}
```

Comment: I meant background size (not 'image')

Comment: You can still edit your question to improve it...Can you create a jsfiddle (markup and css) that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Maybe try adding a [jsfiddle](http://jsffiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

instead of float:left; try:

```
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Why are the social buttons so far out in Chrome? Firefox is doing what I want but Chrome throws it all out?